# F# and Image Processing on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, f#

Well, I have posted a question about F# and fuzzy logic, now trying to widen a little bit my horizon, I'd like to know how much useful can be F# when talking about image processing.

I don't know if image processing field can be a target field when considering F#, another thing I would like to know is whether a developer can build graphic interface using f#. I saw some examples but didn't really understand also because Visual Studio, when trying to create a new project, only shown me the possibility to create console app using f#.

And here comes another question: my interest is developing an f# app able to process images on the web. Is is possible to create a asp.net application in f#? Is Visual Studio ready for F# apps on ASP.NET?
Where can I find a useful guide or reference?

Please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two questions here:

**Can I do image processing?** Like most languages, F# has no built-in syntax for image processing. However, you can use one of a variety of .NET image processing libraries.

**Can I build UIs and web apps?** Any code that you can write in C# or VB.NET you can also write in F#. This includes WinForms apps, WPF apps and ASP.NET apps.

However, the designers in Visual Studio itself currently do not support F#. This means that you must write the user interface code yourself in F#, or (more likely), write a thin UI in C#, and put the core logic in F#.

Comment: Ah ok... one question, is it also possible to write ui in c# and use some libraries in f#??????

Comment: Definitely. F# is a standard .NET language like C# and VB.NET, and you can call into code written in any .NET language from any other .NET language. Although F# code written a functional style tends to look odd when called from C#, it's possible to write F# classes that wrap your functional code and provide a friendly interface for C# developers.